# Jackson TypeReference with generics and Injecting dependency

Tags: kotlin, jackson, cdi

I have a generic CRUD Controller where I would like to have a generic CRUD service. The service has a generic class parameter depending on the model type. Jackson is used for converting the DTO to a Map and pass the values to the service so that it can create the model. But for any reason that I don't understand the TypeReference is resolved with a LinkedHashMap instead of the specialized model defined in the extended controller:

```java
Resulted in: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.basketmaster.backend.common.domain.Model (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.basketmaster.backend.common.domain.Model is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @1baba60f)
```

```kotlin
interface Dto
interface Model { var id: Any? }
interface CrudService<E> { fun create(params: Map<String, Any>): E }

class CrudResource<D : Dto, M : Model> {

    @Inject
    @field: Default
    open lateinit var service: CrudService<M>

    @Inject
    @field: Default
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Post
    fun create(@Valid dto: D): Response {
        val data = objectMapper.convertValue(dto, object: TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {})
        val model = service.create(data)
        return Response.created(URI.create("/${path?.value}/${model.id}")).entity(model).build()
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Default
class CrudServiceImpl<T> : CrudService<T> {

    @Inject
    @field: Default
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    override fun create(params: Map<String, Any>): T {
        val now = Instant.now()
        val p = params + mapOf("creator" to "", "created" to now, "modifier" to "", "modified" to now)

       // HERE IS THE ISSUE:
       // When the injection (CDI) instances this class with a T specialization I don't know why here T is resolved as a superclass type instead of a specialized type.
       // Check the following classes to see how this class is used
        val model = objectMapper.convertValue(params,  object: TypeReference<T>() {}) 

        return model
    }

}

class Exercise(
    var title: String,
    var description: String,
    var duration: Int,
    var goals: List<String>,
    var creator: String,
    var created: Instant,
    var modifier: String,
    var modified: Instant,
    override var id: Any? = null
) : Model

data class ExerciseDto(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val duration: Int,
    val goals: List<String>
) : Dto

@Path("/exercises")
class ExerciseResource : CrudResource<ExerciseDto, Exercise>()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to "type erasure", the compiler checks if "T" is compatible but at runtime, the actual type of T isn't known, it's just an Object.
You can use Kotlin's "reified types" like in:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.registerKotlinModule
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class RefTest {

    private val om = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()

    data class Person(val firstName: String)

    private inline fun <reified T> create(params: Map<String, Any>): T {
        return om.convertValue(params, T::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        assertEquals(Person("Max"), create<Person>(mapOf("firstName" to "Max")))
    }

}
```